# Using sample "world" database to find country with most cities

Tags: mysql

I'm currently learning mySQL. I have noticed that mySQL comes with a "world" database that contains a database of cities from around the world with their respective countries and populations.

I am interested in finding the top 5 countries with the *most* cities using this database (**city** is the name of the table), and this is the query I use:

```
use world;

select `Name`,count(*) 
from  `city` 
group by `Name` 
order by count(*) desc 
limit 5;
```

Is this correct? I am having doubts because for some reason, when I remove the count(*) column, I get different results.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you also removing the `order by`?

Comment: @artm No, I'm keeping the "count(*)" part in each query. I do get some overlap with the results, but they are not identical (which I thought they should be).

Comment: If you want to get countries, you probably should select country-names and group by them, instead of city names.

Comment: @Sirko I see what you mean. I grouped by country names and that has given me a more realistic answer. Was my original query finding the top 5 most common city names?

Comment: When I try this in sql with TOP the results are the same, with or without `, count(*)`. I don't think TOP and LIMIT would work differently though.

Comment: @mel basically yes. MySQL returned one row per city name, which includes the number of entries contributing to that row.

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked a long time ago.
I'm no expert on SQL but I believe you can get the desired result with :

```
select c.name, count(ct.name)
from country c
INNER JOIN city ct
ON ct.countrycode=c.code
group by c.name
order by 2 desc
limit 5 ;
```